# mmm-mode: Implementing C++ mode as a submode

Tags: emacs, elisp

We use an internal scripting language (let's call it `pkc`), which allows for embedding C++ code. The C++ code segments are delimited by `{{{` and `}}}` markers.

I create an emacs mode for this language, using [Generic Mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GenericMode) and [mmm-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MmmMode).

Here is what I got (stripped down non-essential parts for posting here):

```
(require 'generic-x)

(setq pkc-imenu-generic-expression
      '(("macros" "^[ \t]*macro[ \n\t]+\\([a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\)" 1)
        ("functions" "function[ \n\t]+\\([a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\)" 1)
        ))

(require 'cc-mode)      ;; for c++-mode
(require 'mmm-auto)
(setq mmm-global-mode 'maybe)

(define-generic-mode
  'pkc-mode                                  ;; name of the mode to create
  '("//" ("/*" . "*/"))                      ;; comments are same C++ comments
  '( ... )                                   ;; some keywords
  '("\\.pkc$")                               ;; files for which to activate this mode

  ;; other functions to call
  '((lambda ()
      (mmm-mode 1)
      (setq mmm-submode-decoration-level 2)
      (setq imenu-generic-expression pkc-imenu-generic-expression)
      (which-function-mode 1)

      (c-initialize-cc-mode t)
      (c-init-language-vars-for 'c++-mode)
      (c-common-init 'c++-mode)
      (c-update-modeline)

      (message "pkc-mode[mmm] is on")))

  "A mode for pkc source files"                  ;; doc string for this mode
  )

(mmm-add-classes
 '((embedded-c++
    :submode c++-mode
    :face mmm-default-submode-face
    :front "{{{"
    :front-offset -1
    :back "}}}"
    :back-offset 1)))

(mmm-add-mode-ext-class 'pkc-mode nil 'embedded-c++)
```

When I load the source file with embedded C++ code segments, they are highlighted somewhat less than what would have been if C++ mode was the major mode (that's not my problem, however). When the cursor in C++ code, the modeline changes to `pkc/l[C++/l]` (as expected).

The problem is, whenever I press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to indent a line, I get the error `Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`. When I turned on debugger, this is the stack trace I see:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  c-syntactic-skip-backward(nil nil t)
  c-looking-at-decl-block(nil t)
  c-guess-basic-syntax()
  c-indent-line()
  #[nil \302>\203)\212\303 \210\304\305x\210\303 \210\306 )i\306 X\203\"\307    !\202'\212\307  !))\20 \207" [indent-line-function column (indent-relative indent-relative-maybe) beginning-of-line "\n     " nil current-indentation indent-line-to] 2 1908700 nil]()
  c-indent-command(nil)
  c-indent-line-or-region(nil nil)
  call-interactively(c-indent-line-or-region nil nil)
```

Looking at the definition of `c-looking-at-decl-block` and particularly the call to `c-syntactic-skip-backward, I find:

```
    (c-syntactic-skip-backward c-block-prefix-charset limit t)
```

Examining the first argument `c-block-prefix-charset` reveals that its value is `nil`. Doing the same from a plain C++ buffer shows a non-`nil` value. So, I suspect that C++-mode requires some initialization that's not being properly done.

So, my questions are:

1. What am I missing in the C++-mode initialization section in my implementation?
2. Am I using the right approach (combining `generic-x` and `mmm-mode`)? Is there a better approach?

I also see another error (`File mode specification error`) when I load the file, but I suspect the problem is the same or something similar.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I guess you need take a look on this one http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MuMaMo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Rewritten after the discussion in the comments, for any later visitors).

The setup in the question is basically fine, but to work with current `c++-mode` you need to use an updated version of `mmm-mode`. It's available at [the GitHub project page](https://github.com/purcell/mmm-mode) and also at [Melpa](http://melpa.milkbox.net/).

The relevant patches ([one](https://github.com/purcell/mmm-mode/commit/e414b5bde74afcb342c2dfba0e041407b0420304), [two](https://github.com/purcell/mmm-mode/commit/5289a0bc6480c12c51704a3c056a3015e81af1d2), [three](https://github.com/purcell/mmm-mode/commit/545b85d6f1fa209bd767950d84d3fdca2ab1a92d)) added new entries to the value of `mmm-save-local-variables`, which `mmm-mode` uses to decide which local variables to save or restore when leaving or entering a submode region.

From what I understand, a future update to `cc-mode` can add more such vars, so the list may need to be updated from time to time.

Extra tip: to have better indentation in the subregions, you may want to wrap the submode's `indent-line-function` with some code that will narrow the buffer before calling it ([example here](https://gist.github.com/4555250)). Depending on the indentation function (and whether it calls `widen`), it may or may not help.

Comment: thanks for your response. I tried #1 from your possible solutions. Also, added the changes from your linked patch to `mmm-vars.el`. It didn't help. Re your point #2, what are the other modes that "are already there"? Do you mean, any mode that is already derived from cc-mode?

Comment: My patch was merged. Why did you need to add it?

Comment: Sorry about solution 1, it'll work only if the value is set before mmm-mode is loaded. #2 means you use one of the modes in the default value of `mmm-c-derived-modes` for the subregions. `c++-mode`, for example.

Comment: The system where I need this to work is behind multiple layers of network walls and does not have access to the Internet. It was easy to apply the patch manually, rather than jump through several hoops to get the updates.

Comment: Ok, but you may be missing out on other useful fixes. Have you gotten this to work? If not, put the code you already have somewhere where I can easily try it out, I'll try to see what's wrong with it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Please see https://gist.github.com/4542481 for a minimal version of my mode definition and small a test file. I have cut the elisp code to the bare minimum that still produces the error for me. I tried it in both emacs 24.1.50.1 and emacs 23.2.1, and both versions showed the same error.

Comment: If you look at the backtraces now with the patch applied, you should see that they are different. Basically, there are some additional vars that still need `mmm-mode` to be made aware of. I'll cook the new patch later today.

Comment: And here's a trick for better indentation: https://gist.github.com/4555250. It's not perfect, feel free to file an issue.

Comment: Thanks again for looking at this. I tried your fork of mmm-mode (https://github.com/dgutov/mmm-mode). With this, I do not get the errors any more. However, I don't see the effects of mmm-mode at all, when I load my pkc script file. 1) The modeline does not show `[mmm]`. 2) the c++ code used to be rendered with `mmm-default-submode-face`, but now there is no change. 3) When I press the `TAB` in the embedded C++ sections, I see only the default indenting behavior (which is to move the cursor to the position of second word of the previous line).

Comment: (...cont'd) `C-h m` doesn't show any indication that mmm-mode has been loaded.

Comment: That's quite odd, it works fine for me. Do you load `pkc-mode.el` before opening the script file? To test this, I open the `.el` file first, do `M-x eval-buffer`, then open `test.pkc`. If you opened `test.pkc` when `pkc-mode.el` wasn't loaded yet, you can still load it, then switch to the script file buffer and do `M-x pkc-mode`.

Comment: That is exactly what I did (open `pkc-mode.el` -> `M-x eval-buffer` -> open `test.pkc`). I do see `Pkc` in mode-line in the `test.pkc` buffer. Earlier, I used to see `Pkc/l' or `Pkc/l[C++/l]` (when cursor is in C++ section), but I don't see it now. I also tried starting emacs with `-q` option to disable loading my startup files, then adding the location of `mmm-mode` to the `load-path` and repeated the above steps. I see the same result. I am not sure how to proceed from here. I will probably give up on this approach, and try rewriting the mode, this time without using `generic-x`.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what your problem is now. I do see `[MMM]`, `Pkc/l[C++/l]` when appropriate, syntax highlighting and working indentation. Both when starting from my current config or from `emacs -Q`. Look into the `*Messages*` buffer, see if there's anything suspicious there. If you installed my fork in the same directory where the previous version was, check for leftover `*.elc` files.

Comment: Also, if you have an old version of Emacs, try a newer one.

Comment: I removed `mmm-mode` that was installed by the system package manager, and byte-compiled the local `mmm-mode` (copy of your fork). This appears to have fixed the problem. I see the submode rendered appropriately, and with the additional code from your gist, the indentation is indeed better. Thanks very much for your patience and help.

Comment: There does seem to be a tiny problem. Occasionally, I see `Error during redisplay: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil) ...` in the `*Messages*` buffer. I turned on the debugger (globally, even) to get the stack trace, but the debugger isn't triggered when this happens again. Any idea why this could happen?

Comment: Looks like an error during fontification, possibly because I missed yet some other variable. I can't reproduce it, though. You can try evaluating `(font-lock-fontify-region (point-min) (point-max))` in a problematic buffer, then it should trigger the debugger.

Comment: Feel free to create an issue here, for this and any future problems: https://github.com/purcell/mmm-mode/issues

Comment: I needed to add two more variables to the list: `c-macro-with-semi-re` and `c-typedef-decl-key`. See: https://github.com/purcell/mmm-mode/pull/18